# redirect .php to .html extensions 404 error

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to convert all .php files to run with .html extensions but it gives me `404 Page Not found error`:

If I run files with .php extension, it runs well but not with .html extension, I have checked `mod_rewrite is enabled` as well.

I'm having Ubuntu 12 version and PHP 5.3 installed.

htaccess code is as below:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .html
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\.php$
#RewriteRule ^(.*) /$1.html [R=301,L]
```

Please help me, whats wrong?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it works with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L]
```